# How to give specific outputs higher priority in accuracy / reducing loss, when training Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, backpropagation, loss-function

So I am dealing with a simple neural network with 10 inputs and one output. I can have as many hidden layers as suggested, however I am using 2. I am also using "mean_squared_error" loss function and RMSProp optimizer.

Anyhow, the question I have is, lets suppose my output values are like this:
[0,0,3,0,0,0,5,0,0,2,0...] etc. Note, that value 0 repeats more often. So What I would love to do, is to try to force Neural Network to learn better in case "non zero values on the output side". To give more of an "importance" to those values.
Because if I use 'mean_squared_error', the training will try to optimize according to entire dataset, this will lead mostly to optimization of cases, where 0 is an output value.

EDIT:
The problem I am dealing with, could be simple modeling of physical system. Let us say, we have a black-box system with known inputs. This black-box has a single outputs (let us say temperature). Based on our inputs and corresponding outputs, we could model the system using Neural Network as a "black-box" and then use the trained NN to predict temperature.

EDIT:
So I am now using different training/validation set. I was suspecting that there is something wrong with the previous one.
Now I got something like the image above (please see the immediate spike)
[image: Abs Training and Validation Error]
What could cause that?

Keep in mind, I am not experienced in NNs, so literally any feedback are welcomed :)

Answer (score 1):

If your outputs are integers `[0,0,3,0,0,0,5,0,0,2,0...]`, i.e., `classes`, you will probably do a classification. So, your loss should be `categorical_crossentopy`. In this case, there are two ways of doing what you want:

1- You can use SMOTE, Synthetic Minority Oversampling technique so that the non-zero classes get the same weight as the zero-class. For binary classes:

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from imblearn.combine import SMOTEENN

sm = SMOTEENN()
x, y = sm.fit_sample(X, Y)
```

2- You can also adjust Keras class weights:

```
class_weight = {0: 1.,1: 30.}

model.fit(X, Y, nb_epoch=1000, batch_size=16, class_weight=class_weight)
```

Comment: Hi Rubens_ZImbres, thanks for answer. First I would like to note, that the output of NN is not an array of integers. It is rather a simple single integer. Due to confidentiality, I cannot go much into details, but I have add some more explanation to the original post.
So I guess, that I am not dealing with classification problem.

Answer (score 0):

there are two important concepts in ML.

"underfitting" and "overfitting", which in your case I think it's underfitting.

to overcome this problem there are some ways:

1. make your model more complex by adding more layers and units
2. if you are using regularization terms, decrease their values
3. use more features (if there is any)

hope this help you.

Comment: Hi mehran rafiee.
Thanks for your feedback.
I am sure not dealing with overfitting, as the test data has same type/amplitude of error as training/validation data. So we are on the same page here :)
Could be that there is a problem of "underfitting". I have tried you 1.) suggestion but it does not improve.
I am not sure what do you mean by the 2.) point? Could you just quickly point me out?
And about 3.), if with features, you refer to "input to NN", then the answer is "Yes, I tried" :)

Comment: @AljazJelen more features is different from more data. in a dataframe for example we would be talking about columns rather than rows (data points). Also what algorithm are you using?

Comment: about my number 2. : there are some regularization terms like L1 or L2, that could be useful for preventing the overfitting problem.
 
is it possible to share your NN architecture with us? if not, have you tried Batch normalization in your NN layers?
have you tried using "Adam" for the optimizer and "crossentropy" for as the loss function?

Comment: @Mehran, I am dealing with regression, so I do think crossentropy would work.
NN architecture, I can share with you, but I change it all the time, to reach better results. For now I have 4 hidden layers with [50,50,20,10] neurons and one on output stage. All hidden layers are Dense and have Tanh activation function (since inputs are normalized), whereas output layer has ReLu activation function.